# How to tell the learner type of machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

It is my first time to use Azure Machine Learning...

When I have trained 2 models using the same training data and testing data, when it comes to evaluate model, it shows error

> All models must have the same learner type

Do you know what is "learner type" of machine learning models and how to tell the learner type of a model?

Below is the screenshot of my basic practice on Azure Machine Learning:

[image: Azure Machine Learning practice]

Comment: You may read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905896.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models you compare should be of the same type - binary classification, regression, multi-class classification etc. For example, you can't compare effectiveness of linear regression to the effectiveness of logistics regression. They solve absolutely different tasks.

This is the case for you - you try to compare linear regression (which outputs real value) with the multiclass decision forest, which tries to classify input to some class.

Answer (score 1):

The first model that you are comparing is a regression model with continuous target variable and predicts a continuous value for your data.

- Example: A continuous scale of measure of 'quality' like 70.6, 80.5, 90 etc.

The second model that you are comparing is a classification model with multiple classes in the target variable and classifies (also prediction) your data into those multiple classes.

- Example: Your measure of quality now is 'Bad', 'OK', 'Good'

Your trying to evaluate these two models against each other, which won't work out because they don't give out the same/similar output.

So when Azure ML says learner type - here it may mean 'learning to output a continuous value' vs 'learning to output a class'.